# I am trying to execute batch file via python by calling python from c#. only batch file trigger using python script alone not executing

Tags: c#, python-3.x, batch-file, model-view-controller

1. Python trigger from C# program is working fine.
2. Batch script from Python alone is not working.

I am trying to execute a batch file via Python by calling Python from C#. Only batch file trigger using Python script alone not executing
when we run trough MVC application but it works fine when Python scripts runs directly.

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files/Python 3.5/python.exe";
//startInfo.Arguments = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MATS_BAT_Script/Python_Scripts/MATSUpgrade.py";
startInfo.Arguments = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Python_Scripts/MATSUpgrade.py").ToString();

startInfo.Verb = "runas";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
bool t = process.Start();

System.IO.StreamReader myStreamReader = process.StandardError;
string error = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
string test = error;
System.IO.StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
string output = reader.ReadToEnd();

process.WaitForExit();

process.Close();
```

Python:

```python
try:
    writerMATS.save()
    subprocess.run(['C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MATS_History_Load_App\Python_Scripts\Copy_Batch_Trigger.bat'], shell = True, check = True, capture_output = True)
except Exception:
    print(Exception)
```

Batch script:

```
COPY / Y C: \inetpub\wwwroot\MATS_History_Load_App\Python_Scripts\MATSUpgrade.xlsx\servewr ip\Mats\Mats_Test\MATSUpgrade.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a batch file directly. You have to invoke cmd.exe to interpret the batch file for you, e.g.:

`cmd.exe /c C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MATS_History_Load_App\Python_Scripts\Copy_Batch_Trigger.bat`